# Rails json POST passing NULL values

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm unsure why the below cURL calls don't seem to pass the values I expect via json to my Rails 3.2.11 app in Ruby 1.9.3. I have a commodity model with accepts_nested_attributes of prices but using a couple of cURL calls I found on SO, each attribute is coming up with NULL except for the commodity_id which should be a clue. But it's not obvious to me. Of course, the price model has a field for commodity_id and you can see by my call that the issuer has to know that prices are for commodity_id = 1. Both calls below yield the same result it appears. It's probably just a misplaced comma or something but haven't seen it.

commodity.rb

```
 class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :name
   has_many :prices
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
 end
```

prices.rb

```
 class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :buyer, :date, :price, :quality, :commodity_id
   belongs_to :commodity
 end
```

api/prices_controller.rb

```
 module Api
class PricesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

      def create
        commodity = Commodity.find(params[:commodity_id])
         respond_with :api, :commodity, commodity.prices.build(params[:price])   
  end
 end
```

routes.rb

```
 namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
   resources :commodities, only: [:show, :new, :create] do
     resources :prices
   end
 end
```

Here are the two cURL calls:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3004/api/commodities/1/prices -d "{\"commodity\":{\"prices_attributes\":[{\"price\":\'8\',\"buyer\":\"Sam\",\"quality\":\"Bad\",\"commodity_id\":1}]}}"\",\"commodity_id\":1}]}}"
```

The second based on searching SO for NULL responses:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3004/api/commodities/1/prices -d "price[price]=6" -d "price[buyer]=Sam" -d "price[quality]=good" -d "price[commodity_id]=1"
```

They both yield:

```
{"buyer":null,"commodity_id":1,"created_at":null,"date":null,"id":null,"price":null,"quality":null,"updated_at":null}*
```

What am I not seeing? thanx, sam

Answer (score 0):

I think overall your trying to use nested attributes incorrectly.   when you use it correctly your posting only to your commodities controller.   in that case you would do a put to update a commodity with the prices you pass in the prices_attributes.

To get that working you would need to add :prices_attributes to your attr_accessible method of your commodity method

Your example is not storing attributes because the params[:price] doesn't have the data you expect.    params[:commodity][:prices_attributes][0]  has the correct data.   B

if you have the api to post and update or create a single price you should just change your curl to use params[:price] and send data in just a price hash

In general, check the rails console after a post to see what the params look like and make sure they are what you expect.